# how do you have multiple formats to a Columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to do two formats (Money, and column size)
on a single column and cannot get it to work. I've tried

```
COLUMN ColOne FORMAT A50 $99,999.99 

COLUMN ColOne FORMAT A50, $99,999.99 

COLUMN ColOne FORMAT A50 and $99,999.99 

COLUMN ColOne FORMAT A50 
COLUMN ColOne FORMAT $99,999.99

COLUMN ColOne FORMAT A50$99,999.99
```

it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Please post compilable code that you have problems with.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me to want to display a column as a 7 digit number representing a monetary value and a 50 character string at the same time.  What effect would you have?  Forcing every column value to have 40 spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but i dont know reasons to do this. Try to format output data in query.
Force data coersion to varchar2 like this

```
Select ..., lpad(to_char(field,'$9G999G990D99'),50,' ') from....
```